# ComboBox does not select any Item provided from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose my Model class called person looks like below code:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Gender class used in Person class looks like:

```
public class Gender
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

Now in a view called EditView I am trying to display the information of currently selected Person:

```
<Page ...............>

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:EditViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Genders, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Gender}">

            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="6"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="gd" TextElement.Foreground="Black">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Path Grid.Column="0" Data="{Binding ImageData}" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Width="24" Height="24" Margin="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Padding="6"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="#FF4CC4F6"></Setter>
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="#FF84CDFA"></Setter>
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"></Setter>
                                        <Setter TargetName="gd"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ComboBox>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

EditViewModel.cs code:

```
public class EditViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EditViewModel()
    {
        Genders = new ObservableCollection<Gender>(
                                                        from gender in XDocument.Load(DirectoryPaths.DataDirectory + @"Basic\Genders.xml")
                                                                                .Element("Genders").Elements("Gender")
                                                        select new Gender
                                                                    {
                                                                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(gender.Attribute("Id").Value),
                                                                        Name = gender.Element("Name").Value,
                                                                        ImageData = gender.Element("ImageData").Value
                                                                    }
                                                  );
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Gender> _genders;
    public ObservableCollection<Gender> Genders
    {
        get
        {
            return _genders;
        }
        set
        {
            _genders = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Genders");
        }
    }

    private Person _currentPerson;
    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentPerson = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the just relevent code for viewmodel. The property CurrentPerson has a person when EditView is shown. But in the ComboBox I do not get any selection by default. I am able to select values manually. But when the EditView loads I am not able to say the gender of the person as it does not get displayed as SelectedItem of the ComboBox.

Comment: make sure that `Gender` property in initialized and notifying changes.

Comment: Yes Gender Property is initialized and also it is notifying changes.

Comment: Try to set `Gender` property to one of `Gender` instance in `Genders` property. Because I believe `SelectedItem` should be set to one of `ItemsSource` member item

Comment: one more thing to verify. is the instance of Gender in the Person class is from the Genders collection? I suspect not, to me it looks like initialized from another xml. if so then you may either take the appropriate instance from the Genders or implement iequalitycomparer on the gender class

Comment: @pushpraj Yes you are right but can you say me How do I take the appropriate instance from the Genders?

Comment: @har07 How do I make that change?

Comment: don't worry for the correct instance but implement comparison.

Comment: @pushpraj I have created a View called ListView. It contains a DataGrid which is filled up with Persons. I have added an edit button by clicking on which I would be redirected to EditView. When I save changes or click cancel, I return to ListView. But at this time I get nothing selected on the datagrid. I have tried to implement ServiceNavigator as Both views are displayed in a frame one by one. Can you say me : should I override Equals and GetHashCode methods here as well?

Comment: overriding Equals and GetHashCode helps when a container is trying to lookup if it contains a specific item. having these method on Person class may produce unexpected results. in this case you must ensure that the correct instance is passed to edit view and the properties(including selected person etc.) are set property and are notifying the changes.

Comment: @pushpraj I think I am using the SameInstance as SelectedItem of DataGrid is Binding to the Property of ServiceLocator Class's one and only instance. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502250/selectedrow-of-datagrid-is-not-selected-again-after-returning-to-same-page Here my View is same but ViewModels and other implementation is as suggested by you in your demo projet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into a very common problem, two identical `Gender` objects are not equal to each other!

`ComboBox` sees the bound selected item, but doesn't see a matching item (actually, it doesn't see a matching **reference**) so it doesn't select anything.

To fix it, `Gender` needs to override `Object.Equals` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)) and `Object.GetHashCode` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx)). According to this [article](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2009/10/xaml-combobox-selecteditem-binding.html) implementing `IEquatable` will also work.

Comment: I have overridden Equals and GetHashCode() methods. Now I can get the selectedPerson's gender. But when I select any gender from comboBox then I get another error: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'SampleProject.Models.Gender'.

Comment: I have added a condition if(obj is Gender). Now it's working fine.